# click on array picture to go to members homepage using PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I am building a social networking website. I have a pagenation page to show search terms for members, such as this search page:

http://shareads.us/ThumbnailBrowse/ThumbnailBrowse_ML1_New.php

When a picture is clicked on, I would like it to take them to the specific member (in the pic) membership page. Links would also work because I have several membership pages, but of course the info is coming from MySQL and does not have specific links.
I do not know how to click a picture and have the member's page come up from MySQL. I've experimented with hundreds of things, including even an actual

http://shareads.us/encryptedsignin_1/LitePage/LITEsigninpage.php

Then type in the username (not very convenient for people!) and it creates the Member Page by using a WHERE = ('specific name'):

$sql = "select username, zoompicture, FastBrowseusernamepage, litetext FROM sharedinfo LEFT JOIN liteheavy ON sharedinfo.id = liteheavy.userID WHERE username = ('WalterJohnson')";

Which creates:

duh duh duh (follow it through if you wish using the URL at first)

BUT that won't work either! If I had 100 million members I'd have to put each of their
names into ('XXXXXXXXXXXX')"; !!!

I've tried putting $username, username, etc. etc. There's got to be a way of either
entering the username or the 2 dimensional array specific row. Please help?

(And anyone who wants an EQUAL Profit-Sharing Partnership on this website, please write to me: Michael - talkingchinese@yahoo.com

Answer (score 0):

generally when using a variable in this i escape it entirely from the variable.

such as:

```
$sql = "select username, zoompicture, FastBrowseusernamepage, litetext FROM sharedinfo LEFT JOIN liteheavy ON sharedinfo.id = liteheavy.userID WHERE username = '" . $username . "'";
```

would this be useful to your question?